# Error: the update operation document must contain atomic operators, when running updateOne

Tags: mongodb

In my collection, there is only one document.

```
> db.c20160712.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("57ab909791c3b3a393e9e277"), "Dimension_id" : 2, "Attribute" : "good", "Hour" : "20160712_06", "Frequency_count" : 100
```

I want to run `updateOne` to replace the document with another one. But why is there `Error: the update operation document must contain atomic operators`?

```
> db.c20160712.updateOne( { "Attribute" : "good"}, {"Type" : "DVD", "Title" : "Matrix, The", "Released" : 1999, "Genre" : "Action"}, { upsert: true} )
2016-08-10T16:37:57.089-0400 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: the update operation document must contain atomic operators :
DBCollection.prototype.updateOne@src/mongo/shell/crud_api.js:493:1
@(shell):1:1
```

The second and third arguments in the above command comes from an example in [The Definitive Guide to MongoDB: A complete guide to dealing with Big Data ...
By Eelco Plugge, David Hows, Peter Membrey, Tim Hawkins](https://books.google.com/books?id=-qIvCwAAQBAJ&lpg=PA82&dq=the%20definitive%20guide%20of%20mongodb%203ed&pg=PA69#v=onepage&q&f=false)

My MongoDB is 3.2.

Answer (score 218):

Wrong syntax for the second parameter. Please check [the docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateOne/). It should be:

```
db.c20160712.updateOne(
    { "Attribute" : "good" }, 
    { $set: {"Type" : "DVD", "Title" : "Matrix, The", "Released" : 1999, "Genre" : "Action" } },
    { upsert: true }
);
```

Comment: I am a bit puzzled with "I don't just do update" part. What else you expect from **update** function?

Comment: You mean "replace" the document? Then you should follow @dyouberg's advice and use correct function.

Answer (score 48):

I believe this was changed as a side-effect of introducing the `updateOne()` method in addition to `update()` and `updateMany()` as somewhat of a safeguard to prevent user's from accidentally overriding an entire document.

You can use the [`replaceOne()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.replaceOne/) method instead, or an `update()` without specifying `multi:true`.

Answer (score 48):

You should use this code because I was also facing the same problem and then I used this code:

```
updateOne(
    { _id: new ObjectID(req.params.id) },
    { $set: { title: req.body.bookName, author: req.body.authorName } },
    { upsert: true }
)
```

and you should also define **`ObjectID`** otherwise the problem will occur again.

```
const ObjectID = require('mongodb').ObjectID;
```

Answer (score 4):

There are the `"replaceX"` methods, and the `"updateX"` methods.

The answer by @Alex Blex is of the *update* kind, while the PO was attempting (in 2016) to *replace*. Both are valid, albeit they work a bit differently.

The updateX methods, in their second argument, want a document like Alex's: `{ $set: {"Type" : "DVD"... }` where I guess that `$set` is an instance of the *atomic operators* mentioned in the error msg.
With update you can target individual properties of the DB document, leaving the others unchanged.

The *replace* methods take a complete document as the second operand, intended to totally replace the current document existing in the DB.
In this case the second argument is simply the new document, in full. No `$set` or others (there are several, to delete, increment, ...).

In all cases, the first argument is a MongoDB search document, in my case I use the `_id` and prepare it like so:
`let searchDoc = { _id: ObjectID( _id )};`
As @nagender pratap chauhan mentioned, you can't use the `_id`'s string value for matching.
Also, there is some confussion with `ObjectID` and `ObjectId` (upper- or lower- case "D").

The third argument, optional, contains the options.
In the case of the `updateOne` method, stating
`{ upsert: true}`
means that, in case there are no documents satisfying the search criteria stated in the first argument, Mongo should create it.

My code is like so:

```
let searchDoc = { _id: ObjectID( _id )};
this.data = await DAO.db.collection( 'authors' )
.replaceOne(
    searchDoc,                  // filter
    authorData,                 // replacement doc (a JS object)
    {                           // options
        returnOriginal: false,
        sort: [['_id', -1]],
    }
);

return this.data;               // the stored author
```

The `_id` field must not be present in the replacement document, else Mongo would complain about trying to change an immutable field, even if the value is the same as the existing one.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to update all then use empty curly braces before `$set`
example:-

```
db.student_info.updateMany({},{$set:{"fine":0,"maxbook":3}},{upsert:true})
```

I faced the same error because I use this:-

```
db.student_info.updateMany({$set:{"fine":0,"maxbook":3}},{upsert:true})
```